# My Centos AppStream.repo is stuck in 56% update

Tags: centos8

I can't yum update in my centos 8 stream. When i was update yum update, centos AppStream.repo update is stuck in 56% download status and then i got this error below

CentOS Stream 8 - AppStream                                                                                                                                      [   ===                                                                                                                                                  CentOS Stream 8 - AppStream                                                     44% [==================================-                                     CentOS Stream 8 - AppStream                                                     49% [======================================-                                 CentOS Stream 8 - AppStream                                                     55% [===========================================                             CentOS Stream 8 - AppStream                                                     33% [==========================
CentOS Stream 8 - AppStream
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'appstream':

- Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://centos.mirror.net.in/centos/8-stream/AppStream/x86_64/os/repodata/f435d6c37393ca040dca453181d4fcd6df97f03gz [Operation too slow. Less than 1000 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds]
- Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://centos.excellmedia.net/8-stream/AppStream/x86_64/os/repodata/f435d6c37393ca040dca453181d4fcd6df97f0317a68peration too slow. Less than 1000 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds]
- Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for [http://mirror2.totbb.net/centos/8-stream/AppStream/x86_64/os/repodata/f435d6c37393ca040dca453181d4fcd6df97f0317a[Operation](http://mirror2.totbb.net/centos/8-stream/AppStream/x86_64/os/repodata/f435d6c37393ca040dca453181d4fcd6df97f0317a%5BOperation) too slow. Less than 1000 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds]
- Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for http://mirrors.nxtgen.com/centos-mirror/8-stream/AppStream/x86_64/os/repodata/f435d6c37393ca040dca453181d4fcd6df.xml.gz [Operation too slow. Less than 1000 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds]

Comment: Did you read the error messages? Your repositories are slow. This may be passing problem, your internet connection or slow repositories. Change repositories, or wait and try again in a few hours.

Comment: Hi Vidarlo , thanks for your response. My internet speed is 100GB , i already wait an hour but i was face the same problem. How can i change repositories.